# Tensorflow issues when downloading and importing

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, anaconda

I'm trying to use tensorflow more accurately keras but it used tensorflow backend. I have had to convert my python to 3.6.2 in order to download tensorflow and even though it installs when I go to import it doesnt work saying :

**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'**

So i have tried installing Anaconda and performing this input:

```
conda create -n tensorflow_cpu pip python=3.6 #also tried with just tensorflow
activate tensorflow_cpu
pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow
```

Then I get this error:

**ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow_cpu (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow_cpu**

So now I am completely stuck. Why is it so hard to just import a module. Why hasn't tensorflow made the effort to make it work with newer versions of python. I am trying to perform machine learning projects but this issue is demotivating me massively and is turning me away from it all together.

If anyone has a solution or reason could you please let me know it simple matters so i can follow thoroughly. Thanks for your time.

Comment: have you installed the specific version you need from the tensorflow website?

Comment: I wrote a command as solution if it doesn't work anyway just reinstall your python then try to install Tensorflow

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Windows install Python 3.6.x and then Tensorflow as of 8-13-2018 and if you are on Linux just follow this link's instruction https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html .